# Setting default value for Yes/No Data Type in Access table

Tags: ms-access, database-design, ms-access-2010, default-value

I have a Yes/No checkbox in one of my Access tables.  I'd like the default to be 'Yes', so that the box is checked by default.  I cannot get it to work.  This is my selection so far in Design View.

[image]

Am I missing something?  The Datasheet View shows all of the checkboxes unchecked with these settings.

Comment: This is related- I'm also curious how to add a column that is a Yes/No data type when creating a Make Table query in Access.  So to summarize, I'd like to add a new column in a table called "Reportable" that has a Yes/No checkbox that is set to Yes by default.  And would like to know the sql to create that Yes/No column as part of a Make Table query.

Comment: Please don't ask separate questions in the comments. If you have a second question, ask it as a question (you can link to this one if you think it's relevant), and try to provide an attempt/some research

Answer (score 1):

Default values are supposed to be valid expressions, starting with `=`.

Set the default value either to `=Yes` or to `=True` to make checked (Yes) the default.

Answer (score 1):

Change the field's *Default Value* to `-1`, `Yes`, or `True`.

You asked ...

> *Am I missing something? The Datasheet View shows all of the checkboxes unchecked with these settings.*

Beware the *Default Value* is **not** applied to existing records.  It only affects new records when you don't explicitly supply a value.